# Invalid module name of erlang in IDEA run configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, erlang

[trying to run a simple erlang in intellij idea by following most of the instructions online but failed in module name(click to see the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPqMO.jpg)

also tried use the rebar but it stopped at"verifying dependencies"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should move `hello` module inside the directory `src`,as:

[image]